# How do you reverse the direction of a ball if continuously going in one direction?

Tags: javascript, html, simulation, reverse

```js
var velocity = 100;
var positionX = 0;
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');

function moveBall() {
  var Xmin = 0;
  var Xmax = 300;
  
  positionX = positionX + velocity;
  ball.style.left = positionX + 'px';
}

setInterval(moveBall, 100);
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img id="ball" width="150" height="150" src="https://tr.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Volleyball-Ball-icon.png"/>
```

I have declared my global variables, followed by a function to move the ball, then followed by a `setInterval`. However, I can't seem to figure the right way to reverse the ball that continuously moves to the right of my screen until no longer visible. Is it a matter of a type of reverse method or setting up conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution below the `velocity` variable is used to change the moving speed. The `updateDirection()` method is used to change the new direction information by checking the `positionX` value.

```js
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');

/* This variable is used to change the movement speed. */
const velocity = 50;
/* This variable is used to change the amount of movement per unit time. */
const step = 10;
/* This variable stores the current or target position of the <img> element. */
var positionX = 0;
/* This variable stores the minimum position value. */
const xMin = 0;
/* This variable stores the maximum  position value. */
const xMax = 300;
/* true: right move, false: left move */
var direction = true; 

/* This method is used to change the direction of movement. */
function updateDirection() {
  if(positionX == xMax)
    direction = false;
  else if(positionX == xMin)
    direction = true;
}

function moveBall() {
  updateDirection();
  
  if(direction)
    positionX += step;
  else
    positionX -= step;
    
  ball.style.left = `${positionX}px`;
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(`Direction: ${direction ? "right" : "left"} Position: ${positionX} `);
}

/* Update the velocity value to change the movement speed. */
setInterval(moveBall, velocity);
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img id="ball" width="150" height="150" src="https://tr.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Volleyball-Ball-icon.png"/>
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing how you got this done so quick. I've been racking my brain around this for hours. Thank you for taking the time to write out this explanation. It was quite in depth and helpful!

Comment: @lei-marie You need to ask questions in a way that users can test your question. So next time share the codes as text; The question must contain all sub-items so that they can be tested. That's why I edited your question. Thank you also for your good thoughts, keep up the good work.